# What is the difference between int64 and category column type in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code:

```
data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'Joseph', 'Krish', 'John'],'Sex': ['Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female'], 'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18],} 
df=pd.DataFrame(data)   
df['Sex']=df['Sex'].astype('category') 
df.info()
int_cols=[1 if x == 'int64' else 0 for x in df.dtypes ]
print(int_cols)
cat_cols=[1 if x == 'category' else 0 for x in df.dtypes ]
print(cat_cols)
```

When I run it, I am getting error on line `cat_cols=[1 if x == 'category' else 0 for x in df.dtypes ]` but not on `int_cols=[1 if x == 'int64' else 0 for x in df.dtypes ]`

what is the difference between them? How can I change the above code so it works and I get a list of 1,0 for columns that are category?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. pandas 1.3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> [1 if x.name=="category" else 0 for x in df.dtypes]
[0, 1, 0]
```

Comment: what is the difference between int64 and category?